# Request Filtering/URL rewriting with IIS7 - not working

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I cannot get the URL rewriting module to work on my local PC (vista x86)

i set up a new rule using the 'user friendly url' template.

a picture rather than 1000 words....

(the image contains 3 shots - creation, config and pattern test)

http://www.sk8loc8.com/rewriteIssue.jpg

so now that is setup if i request 'localhost/iisrewriteurl/content/5 i should see my content.aspx page.

nope...

Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Detailed Error Information
**Module**  IIS Web Core
**Notification**    MapRequestHandler
**Handler** StaticFile
**Error Code**  0x80070002
**Requested URL**   IISRewriteURL/content/5/
**Physical Path**   C:\Users\Guy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\IISRewriteURL\IISRewriteURL\content\5\
**Logon Method**    Anonymous
**Logon User**  Anonymous

When i go back into the rule itself and test the patterns that IIS made for me, they do not work..

I have tried adding a wildcard script map under the handler mappings section but this makes no difference.

Has anyone seen this type of behaviour before? Or am i missing something very simple?

Answer (score 2):

If you test the pattern you dont need the Host [image: rewrite test]

I always just create Blank Rules and not had a problem that way since not sure if it matters though. I cannot discover why that rewrite wouldnt work perhaps other rules are blocking it?

Comment: that is the fix. i did manage to work it out, but thanks for your input. i cant mark it as the answer as there is some funky stuff going on because i linked my account after i posted a question.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively you may have a look at [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) product that emulates Apache modules behavior on IIS7. It has simpler syntax and Helicon Ape Manager automatically checks the syntax of the rules you write.